# PHP fwrite successful but 404 file not found

Tags: php, html, iis

I have the following code to write a file in PHP.

```
$filename = urlencode($_POST['name']);
$filename .= ".html";
echo $filename;

$handle = fopen("invoices/".$filename, "w");
$bytes = fwrite($handle, $html);
```

That works and I see the file in the directory.

I then display a link to the file like this: `echo "<h2>You can either print the invoice from the following link or send the link to the pharmacy: <a href='invoices/".$filename."'>LINK HERE</a><br />";`

However the link shows a 404 error and so does the file when I view it in my browser. How come? Is this a permissions problem or something?

The file **is** inside the directory and made correctly.

I used the following code and got this output: Wrote 14653 bytes to C:\Inetpub\vhosts\healthinyourhands.co.uk\httpdocs\invoices\invoices\Shivam+Paw.html

```
printf('Wrote %d bytes to %s', $bytes, realpath('invoices/'.$filename));
```

Comment: Try absolute path ?

Comment: Ypou should get the absolute path. realpath(dirname(__FILE__. you file)

Comment: @AndreFerraz that didn't work. `$handle = fopen(dirname(__FILE__)."\\invoices\\".$filename, "w");`

Comment: Use a debugger, its always good to use a debugger because then you can identify where the issue is by your self.